# Android sdk 1.6 WVGA, webview within scrollview is not working

Tags: android, sdk, webview, scrollview

I have added the webview within scrollview in the layout. So data in webview is not fully displayed. Only in android sdk1.6 WVGA resolution, It is not working properly.

This bug is filed in android bug tracker also. For your reference, http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d66d908993d51d65

Can anyone knows how to solve this very big high priority issue.

Comment: If I remember well webview already handles the scrolling, so you don't actually need your scrollview around it. Do you really need it?

Answer (score 0):

the webview scroll bars appears automatically so you don't need to nest into a ScrollView!

> You should not put scrollable items
>   (e.g., WebView) in a ScrollView.
>   --  Mark Murphy (a Commons Guy)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my scenario, I need to add a dynamic content in a webview and textview.  I attached a sample code which contains a webview within scrollview which can be referred in this link http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10338. IT is working fine in all emulators except in 1.6 sdk WVGA resolution emulators.